# How would I get a Google Maps style interactive map on my game's site?

Tags: google-maps, mapping, interactive

I run the RPG campaign called Yarona: Darkness Ascending. I also run the site http://diebot.org/ and I want to incorporate what's found at http://www.uesp.net/oblivion/map/obmap.shtml using my own continents, but where do I start?

Ok, I admit, Frank has a good point, I didn't consider that the external link could go offline 3 months down the road, then my question looses key information. My apologies.

What I have is a campaign that takes place on the world known as Yarona. I also have a large, world-atlas style map/graphic. what I want is to have a Google Maps style interface so my players can zoom out to continents, or zoom in as tight as city blocks, maybe even include "Special Place Pins".

Depa suggests that I try to get help from Google first. I did try that. The only thing I found was about maps of Earth, Earth and more Earth. Depa also suggested I include the code I've used so far, and I would have done so. The thing is that, to reiterate (and please forgive me if I seem flippant):

> Where Do I Start?

Comment: It might be a good idea to make your question more self-contained, by explaining what you want in more detail (besides just providing the links). Besides making your question easier to answer (though not by me -- out of my expertise), it will make the Q&A more useful for those who might come across it later (when those links might be dead, anyway). Just a thought. Welcome to SO!

Comment: It's usually considered good form in SO to include the code you have attempted to use, as well as explaining why it's not working for you and any error messages you may be getting. If you need a full-fledged tutorial for development projects that involve several different tasks, usually Google will be more useful than SO.